# When clicked on image stay on hover state

Tags: html, button, hover, click, state

I need to add function to this code that when it is clicked on button it stay on hover state (coloured)
Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

```
<style>
menucko a { position: relative; left: -210px; transition: left .25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: left .25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: left .25s ease-in-out; } 
menucko a:hover { position: relative; left: 0px; }

bannerik div { margin-left: 2px; border-left: 4px solid #E5D96D; }
</style>

<menucko>
<a href="http://www.bieladuha.sk/kreativne-potreby-akcie"><img class="fade" src="http://www.webareal.sk/fotky25131/web/kreativne-potreby-akcia.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="40" /></a>
</menucko>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/50/

Comment: Now currently what is happening,wats the problem

Comment: Apply the same color to :visited

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the anchor tag using javascript/jQuery

```
$('menucko a').on('click', function () {
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
});
```

Then you could add the `hovered` class to your css

`menucko a:hover, menucko a.hovered { position: relative; left: 0px; }`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help and response. I am really sorry but it is not working, because every button is linked to different page on the site and then it refreshes.. Is there any other solution?